# Where to ask a question about multiple websites running on the same codebase

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know where to ask this question on the Stack Exchange Network.

I think that the answer would be too long and maybe too general.

I don't know whether if it should be asked only once as a complete question or if I should separate it into more than one question.

The Question:

> I have a php website that is hosted online. I want to use the website php files to build more than one website using the same main php files. Something similar to the Exchange Network. To be more specific I mainly want the following features in my website.
>
> - Use the same php files on the main server to build the other websites.
>
>   - I don't want to copy the php files to the other servers. So when i change a file in the main server the change is applied on the other websites.
>   - The other websites will be on different domains, or maybe sub-domains. i.e: if the main website has the domain `www.example.com`, the other websites' domains could be `info.example.com` or `www.example2.com`.
>   - Every website has it's own database which stores only it's data.
>   - If the user registered on one of the network's websites, he is registered in all of the network's websites. i.e: if the user registered in the website `www.example2.com`, and then he opened the website `info.example.com` for the first time in his life, the `info.website.com` should consider him as a current user in the network.
>   - Every one of the websites has **a special settings** that differs from the other websites of the network. For example, the page's title and the welcoming sentence both exist on all the networks' websites, but they are not the same in content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is off-topic and doesn't appear to be about SE

Comment: @fionaredmond The question **is** on topic. Please read the site-recommendation tag: "Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it stands your proposed question is not suitable for any site on the SE network.

**Why?** Because it doesn't actually contain a question - **it is just a list of requirements**.

In addition, it doesn't follow the suggestions outlined in [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

In other words, **what have you tried already to solve your issue?** and **what is your actual question?**